# $_POST is empty in nginx

Tags: php, python, post, nginx

I am using python's *urllib* to send POST request to a PHP program:

```
phonehome_url = "example.com/phonehome.php"
urllib.urlopen(phonehome_url, site_info);
```

site_info is an array like this: `[{'name': 'Technische Universitaet Muenchen', 'url': 'http://www.tum.de', 'site_id': 11599, 'longitude': 11.5669, 'login_base': 'tumple', 'latitude': 48.1493}]`.

But the `phonehome.php` receives empty `$_POST`. My webserver is nginx. 
Any idea? I already tried modify the fastcgi-params, doesn't work.

---

And I tried the same thing on Apache without this problem.

Comment: a german boy? Hallo Welt! :) how do you have configured the webserver (as a proxy)? using Rewriting (then try to ass **Query String Append** on your rules).

Comment: :) I setup the server by using LNMP package without too much modifications, I don't know what went wrong there.

Comment: okay. How is implementes PHP? As a Wrapper? What is then you try to make an simple POST-Request like: <form method="post"><input type="submit" name="test" value="Hello World" /></form><?php print_r($_POST); ?>

Comment: It will give you something like `Array ( [test] => Hello World ) `

Comment: Okay, then your Webserver working correctly. I think the problem is on the urrlib. Otherwise you can use cURL

Answer (score 0):

Did I get it right, but normally the request type is GET. http://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html

Comment: You are right. But with the second argument, it will be a post.

Comment: Ok, that seems to be true. Sorry.